# How to make such animation components in the website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, design-patterns

I came across this website by Google, https://yourplanyourplanet.sustainability.google/
 It has some components such as water, energy etc which are animated.
My question is how to make such components and add animations to it, it includes the designing part of that component.

Answer (score 1):

The animated content is a drawing on a canvas (using javascript to draw it).
An (obfuscated) code can be found [here](https://yourplanyourplanet.sustainability.google/version/1555952149281/js/app.js), and some simple tutorial can be found on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations).